# Spectral lines vs Envelope of PWM wave

Tags: pwm, fourier, sine, harmonics, duty-cycle

On the [wiki page of 'Duty Cycle'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_cycle) there is a nice animation that shows the frequency spectrum of PWM wave as its duty cycle is modulated from 0 to 100%.

The animation shows the 'spectral lines' as well as the 'envelope' of the spectrum.

What I understand is that the 'spectral lines' are the individual frequency components starting from its DC value, and 1st 2nd 3rd.. harmonic components.

What I don't understand is the meaning of 'envelope'? What does that signify practically? are there infinitely many sub-harmonic components 
of the waveform whose limiting values gives the 'envelope' of the spectrum or is it just the mathematical function that join together all the harmonic components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that animation, *envelope* refers to the continuous line that connects the discrete frequency points.  It need not have a closed-form function, but in this case it does, related to the absolute value of the sinc function,  \$\left|{\frac{sin\left({\pi x}\right)}{\pi x}}\right|\$

Comment: What is the practical and physical meaning of the points which fall on the 'envelope'? For example all envelope points between 1st and 2nd harmonic spectral lines?

Comment: I recommend you read up on the Fourier Transform and Z Transform of the square wave, which will be the sinc function.  The obvious practical meaning is that this is the energy present at that frequency, but I suspect you're looking for something else.

Comment: ... and "harmonic" usually refers to the base frequency of of the signal -- i.e., \$\frac{1}{T}\$ for the square wave.  You are using the term wrong here.  Each frequency point is at some fraction of the *sample frequency*, not the square wave frequency.

Comment: Sample twice as fast, and you will have double the points in the spectrum.

Comment: Where are the 'harmonic' frequencies in this spectrum?

Comment: The Fourer math uses "correlation" as its only method to detect energy in a signal. For a 100 Hz square wave, there is strong correlation at 300 and 500 and 700... .... and **SOME** correlation at 2100 and some weakly at 21,100 and all other N * 100 correlations. Finite time duration of the correlation math allows bleed-thru into nearby correlators, thus 21,099 will also show some energy. "Harmonics" show up, because of the math under correlation. Analog spectrum analyzers also show these "harmonics" because the analog filters have (weak) response to faster Integer-related input pulses.